# Align text with a picture

Tags: html, image, alignment

I wish to align my text with my picture. The text cannot go outside the borders of the picture and should be placed under it. I have tried putting it in containers and divs but have not yet succeeded.

On the picture you will see the current situation (picture 1) and the wanted situation (picture 2).

[image]

Current code (after changing it a lot)

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <a href="testing"><img src="test.jpg" width="800px" height="150px"></a><br/>
    <p align="left"> This a test. 
</p>
  </div>  
  <br>
```

Comment: See original post.

Comment: the text will expand to fill the div ,so you should set a fixed with on the div and make the image width 100%

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: Upvoted because of unexplained downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width to the `<div>` instead of the `<img>` and center it with `margin:auto;`:

```
<div style="text-align:center;width:300px;margin:auto;">
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvc64ojw/)

You can also make the div `display:inline-block;` and set `text-align:center;` to the containing element:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
   <div style="text-align:center;width:300px;display:inline-block;">
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvc64ojw/1/)

Comment: Works fine. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

**HTML**

```
<div class="img_cont">
    <a href="testing" class="img_link"><img src="test.jpg" class="the_img"></a><br/>
    <p class="text"> This a test. 
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img_cont{
    width:200px; //or any other width
    height:auto;
}
.testing{
    text-decoraion:none;
    border:none;
}
.the_img{
    width:100%; //make the image fill the container to the full
    height:auto; // in order to maintain the aspect ratio of the image
}
.text{
    // your text styles go here
}
```

Comment: It is still going outside the borders of the picture